Can't figure out how to get react roles working with the example in discord.py
So I'm programming a bot for my dnd and lancer group with absolutely zero experience. I'm mostly stringing example code together and then making it work. I am currently stuck on trying to get the example code for reaction roles, seen in it's entirety here
My current code is as such
# This example requires the 'members' and 'message_content' privileged intents to function.

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import logging

description = '''Godawful bot programmed by my discord username

Primary use case is rolling dice and helping with scheduling for sessions. Also supposed to do reaction roles'''

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='p;', description=description, intents=intents)
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='platform.log', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})')
    print('------')

@bot.command()
async def roll(ctx, dice: str):
    """Rolls a dice in NdN format."""
    try:
        rolls, limit = map(int, dice.split('d'))
    except Exception:
        await ctx.send('ERROR:Syntax - Format has to be in NdN!')
        return

    result = ', '.join(str(random.randint(1, limit)) for r in range(rolls))
    await ctx.send(result)

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.role_message_id = '1249373090727858259'  # ID of the message that can be reacted to to add/remove a role.
        self.emoji_to_role = {
            discord.PartialEmoji(name=''): '1249516324603035689',  # ID of the role associated with unicode emoji ''.
            discord.PartialEmoji(name=''): '1249516335696973884',  # ID of the role associated with unicode emoji ''.
            discord.PartialEmoji(name='green', id=0): 0,  # ID of the role associated with a partial emoji's ID.
        }

    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
        """Gives a role based on a reaction emoji."""
        # Make sure that the message the user is reacting to is the one we care about.
        if payload.message_id != self.role_message_id:
            return


bot.run('bot key thing', log_handler=handler)

Does anyone have any clue as to why the reaction role thing isn't working? The dice roller works fine
I've tried all sorts of variations of the original code found here including just creating a new application and giving it all the right permisisons and just trying that and it still won't work

It seems like you want something to happen when a reaction is added to a message, and this "something" should be defined in the scope of the on_raw_reaction_add function. It's currently only returning None, and doing nothing else.

from the example you linked, you need to add the entire "on_raw_reaction_add" function, the most vital bit being
try:
    role_id = self.emoji_to_role[payload.emoji]
except KeyError:
    # If the emoji isn't the one we care about then exit as well.
    return

role = guild.get_role(role_id)
if role is None:
    # Make sure the role still exists and is valid.
    return

try:
    # Finally, add the role.
    await payload.member.add_roles(role)
except discord.HTTPException:
    # If we want to do something in case of errors we'd do it here.
    pass

